# Vertical position is ambiguous, conflicting contraints

Tags: ios, autolayout, interface-builder

I am getting the following warnings in my view controller, and I would like to understand why. Please see the image.

[image: Image of view controller]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What are you hoping to accomplish with the `>= 16` constraints?  Your card has a fixed size of `200 x 320` due to the `width = 200` and `width:height = 5:8` constraints.  Your card is centered both horizontally and vertically in the Safe Area, so size and placement are fully specified without the `>=` constraints. Besides, setting `>=` constraints on both sides of the card is ambiguous information.  It's like if I told you to stand on a bridge at least 1 meter from each end.  There are many ways to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works perfectly fine on my Xcode 9.4.1 [Link to the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3Lf5.jpg). Can you please click on the red arrow beside `View Controller Scene` to see what is the reason behind the ambiguity of the constraints.

Comment: You just made me realize I had to remove the top contraint!  Actually I also removed the right contraint, I realized that I just need a vertical and horizontal contraint since the rectangle is centered. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You're giving it a specific `width` that's 200, but you're also telling that `UIView` to have a `leading` and a `trailing` to `Safe Area` with 16 points each. Then you're also telling that `UIView` be certered but you gave it a `bottom` constraint as well. All of this make it the location of your `UIView` ambiguous.

Try this:

- Remove the ratio you've set
- Remove the `leading` and then the `trailing` constraints OR the `width` constraint
- Remove the `bottom` constraint as well

Comment: Actually, I want to implement the following constraints : >= 16 points from top, bottom, left and right, aspect ratio of 5:8  and width as high as possible while still satisfying the previous constraints. I don't see why there are conflicting contraints... And why would my position be ambiguous? Thanks again!

Comment: If you have bottom, left, top and right this is enough to satisfy your constraints. You dont need width, nor height, nor 5:8. Let me put it this way, if you set a width of 300 for example and you also have 15 points leading and trailing, this is ambiguous because you set the view to be 200 but you also want it to be 15 points from the left and the right. The compiler needs to break a constraint because it cannot satisfy all of them. You might want to take a look at some Autolayout tutorials to figure out how constraints work.

Comment: Actually it is only at least 16 points, >= 16. I just want to make sure that the rectangle looks nice in both landscape and portrait mode. And I need the aspect ratio to be 5:8. It is actually supposed to be a card. Then, after all this is set, I want the card to take as much space as possible. I thought could use priorities do do this, but it obviously doesn't work. I am following the Stanford Swift course by Paul Hegarty : https://itunes.apple.com/ca/podcast/developing-ios-11-apps-with-swift/id1315130780?mt=2

Comment: Oh I think I figured it out, it works when I remove the top contraint!

Answer (score 0):

[image: edited]

try to remove Height and width and add leading, top, Trailing, Bottom constraints to make view autoresize in all devices.

Comment: If you set `width` and `height` along with `centerX` and `centerY` you don't need `top` and `bottom` really.

Comment: yes but should it auto resize  view size in all devices? without using those constraints (Top and bottom)

Comment: If you want dynamic size of the `UIView`, you shouldn't fix the `width` and the `height`. You should set those `top`and `bottom` constraints to expand the `UIView` in correlation to the device orientation. But it all depends on what the OP wants to achieve with this `UIView`